# How to conform custom class with optional properties to "hashable" protocol

Tags: swift, option-type, hashable

Suppose I have a base class "Person" that I want to add to a Set (List) and need to therefore conform to Hashable and Equatable:

```
class Person : Equatable, Hashable {
let firstName: String
let lastName: String
var nickname: String?
let dateOfBirth: NSDate
var hashValue: Int {
    if let nickname = nickname {
        return firstName.hashValue ^
               lastName.hashValue ^
               nickname.hashValue ^
               dateOfBirth.hashValue
    } else {
        return firstName.hashValue ^
               lastName.hashValue ^
               dateOfBirth.hashValue
    }

}

init (firstName: String, lastName: String, nickname: String, bornOn dateOfBirth: NSDate) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName  = lastName
    self.nickname = nickname
    self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return
        lhs.firstName   == rhs.firstName    &&
        lhs.lastName    == rhs.lastName     &&
        lhs.nickname    == rhs.nickname     &&
        lhs.dateOfBirth == rhs.dateOfBirth
}
```

This class has only a single optional property, which makes the dealing with the optional in the creation of the hashvalue fairly reasonable. What if there were 2 or more optional properties? I can see this getting out of hand quite quickly.

How are optional properties generally dealt with when conforming an object to the hashable protocol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation of the hash value does not have to be based on all properties. In fact, it doesn't need to be based on any. You could simply return a hard coded number though you shouldn't.

Simply return a hash value of one or more of the non-optional properties.

The only rule is that two objects that compare as equal must also return the same hash value. But there is no requirement that two objects with the same hash value much compare as equal.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. 

Perhaps a topic for its own separate discussion, but: Is there any disadvantage to reducing the specificity of the hashValue calculation that may cause issues in the future?

Comment: A poor hash value might lead to performance issues when storing objects in a collection.

Comment: `hashValue` can also be used an optimization for `==` when `==` is expensive. You can quickly discard obviously unequal values if their hashes are unequal. `hashValue` should be O(1) to compute.

Comment: @RobNapier smart! Makes sense. Thanks for the additional tip.

Answer (score 0):

Would just like to add that a class does not need to conform to the Hashable or Equatable protocol to be used as the elements of an Array (which is what I assumed you meant by a List). It is only necessary to conform to Hashable and therefore Equatable, if you want to use the class as an element in a Set or as a Key for a Dictionary. As specified in the [API reference of Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/hashable):

> You can use any type that conforms to the Hashable protocol in a set
>   or as a dictionary key.

Comment: You need to conform to Equatable if you want to lookup objects in an array using, for example, the `index(of:)` or `contains` methods.

Comment: Yes, for convenience, if you want to avoid having to pass closures to the `index(of:)` and `contains` and only pass the element itself.